# Enabling FOS User Bundle Email Registration

Tags: php, symfony, email, fosuserbundle, registration

I bought a third party php script and I'm attempting to enable email confirmation for it. It's made by someone else. I've contacted them and gotten no response, I'm not looking for a definitive answer more so just advice but I see there's a FOS User Bundle in the package.json requirements as well as a "RegistrationController.php" in the script. When the user registers, it directs straight to the "Registration Successful" page after ensuring the input fields are the correct data type.

In the config yml, I enabled registration confirmation and in the parameters.yml I used gmail as the host then I did `composer install` but it's still straight to the registration successful page after inputting email and what not. I was hoping that if I enabled registration in the config.yml that somewhere in the php, this would be recognized but maybe this isn't the case and there's some more coding that has to be done, does this sound right?

RegistrationController.php

```
/*
 * This file is part of the FOSUserBundle package.
 *
 * (c) FriendsOfSymfony <http://friendsofsymfony.github.com/>
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

namespace FOS\UserBundle\Controller;

use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\GetResponseUserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

/**
 * Controller managing the registration.
 *
 * @author Thibault Duplessis <thibault.duplessis@gmail.com>
 * @author Christophe Coevoet <stof@notk.org>
 */
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    private $eventDispatcher;
    private $formFactory;
    private $userManager;
    private $tokenStorage;

    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, FactoryInterface $formFactory, UserManagerInterface $userManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
        $this->formFactory = $formFactory;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->userManager->createUser();
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE, $event);

        if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
            return $event->getResponse();
        }

        $form = $this->formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_SUCCESS, $event);

                $this->userManager->updateUser($user);

                if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                    $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
                    $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
                }

                $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

                return $response;
            }

            $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
            $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_FAILURE, $event);

            if (null !== $response = $event->getResponse()) {
                return $response;
            }
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/register.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Tell the user to check their email provider.
     */
    public function checkEmailAction(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->getSession()->get('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');

        if (empty($email)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_register'));
        }

        $request->getSession()->remove('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email');
        $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($email);

        if (null === $user) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->container->get('router')->generate('fos_user_security_login'));
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/check_email.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Receive the confirmation token from user email provider, login the user.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param string  $token
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function confirmAction(Request $request, $token)
    {
        $userManager = $this->userManager;

        $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);

        if (null === $user) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with confirmation token "%s" does not exist', $token));
        }

        $user->setConfirmationToken(null);
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRM, $event);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_registration_confirmed');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED, new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response));

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Tell the user his account is now confirmed.
     */
    public function confirmedAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
        }

        return $this->render('@FOSUser/Registration/confirmed.html.twig', array(
            'user' => $user,
            'targetUrl' => $this->getTargetUrlFromSession($request->getSession()),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    private function getTargetUrlFromSession(SessionInterface $session)
    {
        $key = sprintf('_security.%s.target_path', $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getProviderKey());

        if ($session->has($key)) {
            return $session->get($key);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

I found that the issue with it going straight to the success page was because it was in prod mode, after switching to dev mode and enabling confirmation, it directs to the login page, unfortunately, it's not sending an email and of course, the login page isn't the desired redirect but I found some error in the log that I think might be relevant

```
[2018-08-27 09:29:51] doctrine.DEBUG: "START TRANSACTION" [] []
[2018-08-27 09:29:51] doctrine.DEBUG: INSERT INTO directory_platform_users (username, username_canonical, email, email_canonical, enabled, salt, password, last_login, confirmation_token, password_requested_at, roles, is_verified, created, modified) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) {"1":"dan4","2":"dan4","3":"dan4@gmail.com","4":"dan4@gmail.com","5":false,"6":null,"7":"$2y$13$4.XnFG.PC3Zholme.w4 [...]","8":null,"9":"2R1Z3Qmek2j--loZNXXWcb8TWU [...]","10":null,"11":[],"12":null,"13":"2018-08-27 09:29:51","14":"2018-08-27 09:29:51"} []
[2018-08-27 09:29:51] doctrine.DEBUG: "COMMIT" [] []
[2018-08-27 09:29:51] translation.WARNING: Translation not found. {"id":"Hi,\n\nyour user account has been succesfully created. Your account name is %username% and e-mail account is %email%.","domain":"messages","locale":"en"} []
[2018-08-27 09:29:52] app.ERROR: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. z13-v6sm5400096ioj.51 - gsmtp " [] []
[2018-08-27 09:29:52] request.INFO: Matched route "listing_my". {"route":"listing_my","route_parameters":{"_controller":"DirectoryPlatform\\FrontBundle\\Controller\\ListingController::myAction","_route":"listing_my"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/listings","method":"GET"} []
[2018-08-27 09:29:52] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2018-08-27 09:29:52] security.DEBUG: Access denied, the user is not fully authenticated; redirecting to authentication entry point. {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AccessDeniedException(code: 403): Access Denied. at /home/dan/directory-platform-1.0.8/directory-platform/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php:68)"} []
[2018-08-27 09:29:52] security.DEBUG: Calling Authentication entry point. [] []
[2018-08-27 09:29:52] request.INFO: Matched route "fos_user_security_login". {"route":"fos_user_security_login","route_parameters":{"_controller":"fos_user.security.controller:loginAction","_route":"fos_user_security_login"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/login","method":"GET"} []
[2018-08-27 09:29:52] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
```

It also adds the user to the database which I checked in mysql. I'm not sure if this is the desired behavior or not though. I don't think that email confirmation is an intended behavior of this php script, otherwise there would be a confirmation page redirect instead of it going to the login page.

Edit: I'm working on localhost so I used gmail and set it up as such

## FOS User

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: DirectoryPlatform\AppBundle\Entity\User
    from_email:
        address: me@gmail.com
        sender_name: name
    registration:
      confirmation:
        enabled: true
```

## parameters.yml

```
mailer_transport: gmail
mailer_host: ~
mailer_user: me@gmail.com
mailer_password: password
```

And that seems to work, still have to find a way to alert the user an email has been sent but oh well.

Comment: create a event listener for event `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` and adjust it to send email with confirmation link to the input email and set registration status as pending. Once user clicks on confirmation link set the user status as confirmed or active and continue as desired

Comment: Try with $user->setEnabled(false);   I haven't at my local but setEnabled will activate account directly. To override entire response you can go with @SanThapa suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a parameter for `fos_user`. I set it to

**config.yml**

```
registration:
  confirmation:
    enabled: true
```